# Denoising technique for signal with beforehand known shape (linear and exponential)

Tags: smoothing, signal-processing, filter, wavelet

I have a noisy signal which is linear and then exponential. I know the type (Gaussian additive noise) and degree (0.01) of noise. Part of the challenge is determining when the signal changed from linear to exponential. What is the best approach to denoise it?

I have tried to apply a Savitzky-Golay filter but the first derivative does not convey useful information. Please see pic below.

[image: Savitzky-Golay filter applied to the data]

Code below:

from scipy.signal import savgol_filter

cleaned_signal = savgol_filter(clean_signal, 11, 1, 1)

Comment: Clarifications needed: Do you want to filter the signal (get the best estimate as of the latest sample) or smooth it (extract the signal at points in time after you have acquired points both in that point's past and future). Do you know any signal parameters ahead of time -- e.g., slope & intercept during the linear period, or parameters in the exponential period, or is just the form assumed?  Do you know the time of the transition from linear to exponential ahead of time, or is that to be determined also? Is this multivariable? Do you know the Gaussian variance?

Comment: Thank you gms for your reply. I actually want to smooth it. I do not knowo any signal parameters ahead of time, just the form. The time of transition is to be determined also. Just univariate. I know the Gaussian variance.

Comment: The chart says the green line is the derivative, but the text above says "second derivative."  The 0 values suggests it is indeed second derivative.  However, it doesn't seem possible that either the first or second derivative would remain constant during the second period (exponential growth period), since the derivative of an exponential function is also an exponential function.  Visually, it seems obviously nonzero.  Maybe there's a bug?   What is your window size in both time and number of samples?  Is the x-axis a sample number or a time variable?

Comment: I used scipy.signal import savgol_filter. Please see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't know scipy - someone else will have to comment on that

Comment: So it looks like a window length of 11 points, 1st order polynomial, 1st order derivative.  Either the filter isn't working, or there's a problem getting the data in or out. "clean_signal" appears to be the raw data; "cleaned_signal is the smoothed data.  Maybe try filling in "clean_signal" with a non-noisy straight line to see if you get the right derivative, to see if the problem is in the filter function?  All the derivatives should be positive,  steady at first, then exponentially increasing after the shift.  Something went wrong here - it looks like you are just filtering zero-mean noise.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know that the signal is a straight line for part 1, you could start with doing a linear least squares fit over a moving time window.  An easy way to do that would be to use Savitzky-Golay smoothing, choosing a linear fit:  you choose a time window size (number of points).  You apply the smoother at each time point, and it does the linear fit based on the data within the surrounding time window.  It is explained in the Wikipedia article, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter .  They give several variations for handling the starting point, where you don't have a full window size available.

Then, you'd want to detect the time when the exponential signal starts for part 2.  That should be obvious - the deviations between the estimate (smoother output) and the original data will start getting bigger and bigger (assuming you're monitoring exponential growth, not shrinking).  Since you know the variance, you could test for the difference from the prediction vs. the raw data.  Or alternatively, you could also use the Savitzky-Golay smoother that estimates the smoothed derivatives, not the smoothed values.  During the linear period 1, the derivative estimate should be very close to constant.  During the exponential period 2, the derivative estimate should be a function of the input signal.

Once you have picked the transition point, you could keep the previous smoothed values within part 1.  For part 2, you could transform the data by taking the logarithm for each data point in part 2 and again do linear fitting.  After that straight line fit, transform the smoothed log values back by applying the exponential function.

Comment: Please see my edit on the top.